# Search for elements that have a particular attribute in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

One element of my mongo collection has the following schema (and represents one poker hand).

```
{
    "players":
        [
            {"active":true,"seat":1,"stack":1769,"screenName":"schla"},
            {"active":true,"seat":3,"stack":2000,"screenName":"galgegla"},
            {"active":true,"seat":4,"stack":483,"screenName":"khrier"},
            {"active":true,"seat":5,"stack":2813,"screenName":"frrou4535"},
            {"active":true,"seat":6,"stack":4002,"screenName":"Guabounai"}
        ],
    "rounds":[],
    "gameNum":"1030564654564",
    "time":"2013/12/21 21:12:03"
}
```

I'd like to search for all hands in my collection that have at least one time the player with screenName **"galgegla"** inside the players array.

Comment: So, you have an array of these objects, and you want to filter them on weather or not they contain a "galgegla" user in the players array?

Comment: Yeah I'd like to filter them based on whether they have a player which screenname is galgegla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your collection is called 'hands', you can do following:

```
db.hands.find( { 'players.screenName': 'galgegla' } )
```

See example under '**Match a Field Without Specifying Array Index**' here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index

Comment: great, didn't know mongo could match a field like this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a.filter(function(arr){
    return arr.players.filter(function(player){
        return player.screenName == 'galgegla';
    }).length;
});
```

Assuming `a` is a array of those objects.

It filters the array of objects based on weather or not a filter on the object's players array returns any results.

... But of course I didn't consider mongo's native functionality, so the other answer'd be more effective. (But possibly not as efficient)

Comment: That doesn't use mongo, so I will accept the other answer.

Comment: Yea, I completely overlooked that :P